# Azure App Service - url for website not working

Tags: python, azure, kudu

I have been trying to publish my first ever Django web application and going through many hurdles over the last two days, I am still unable to access it via the url - it's not live.

I have published it from VS2017, set up continuous deployment from VSTS, installed Python 3.6 extension, updated my web.config file, installed required packages in Kudu, the app is redirected to a cloud-based data base.

I followed the various documentation sites to the letter e.g.: [Deploy your app to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy?correlationId=15e6d8af3bb51-0f0d149521893a8-12656e4a-100200-15e6d8af3bca7&clientId=229039363.1505076377) and [Managing Python on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service)
but I still can't just browse to my url - I am getting a welcome page saying "Your App Service app has been created" and some tutorials.

What am I missing? What is the final stage that I need to do to make it go live?

Responding to the comment below, I have updated my web.config file in KUDU with the following code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.wsgi_app"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When trying to run my url I am getting an internal server error, and when I go to Python log file I am getting the following message:

```
D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\runserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you update your post for more details, about the `web.config` content, what web framework you used like `Django`/`Flask`, etc?

Comment: post updated. Thanks.

Comment: I have spent a further couple of days trying absolutely everything, to the point of no longer knowing what I'm doing and the only result is that I can no longer see the shell website, instead I am getting errors: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred or You do not have permission to view this directory or page. I think time to give up...

Comment: @A. Lukas Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you had solved partial issues in your another thread [How to deploy Django app on Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244939/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-azure/), which I have solved it and posted my answer.

Please refer to it and the `completed configuration` as below:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="DjangoWebProject1.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python362x86\python.exe|D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```