# How to deploy Django app on Azure?

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure-web-app-service

I have posted before but not received an answer. 
I have a Django web app developed in VS2017. I have published it but getting a server error. Can you please advise how I need to configure my web.config file so that it works? Currently it's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.wsgi_app"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python361x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but I am getting an server error and Python log file says:

D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\runserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I have finally managed to deploy my app! If you have a similar problem make sure to update the WSGI_HANDLER with YOUR app's name: "MYAPPNAME.wsgi.application. Then, one more thing you need is to add your url to ALLOWED_HOSTS in your Django's settings.py file. However, none of the css files works at the moment, so still need to figure this out.

Comment: Hi, Lukas.Any progress?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `static files url configuration` to `web.config` file on KUDU which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-python-configure).

I've tried to deploy my own Django project to azure and use your `web.config` file,and it works well.

You could refer to the `web.config` configuration as below:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="DjangoWebProject1.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python362x86\python.exe|D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Note***:

Please make sure the value of `path` property in

`<add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python362x86\python.exe|D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>`

is the same as the value of `url` property in

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Comment: @A. Lukas  Any progress?

Comment: Jay, thank you for your answer. I felt so discouraged by my failed attempts to deploy the static files, that I have given up completely. When I change debug mode to FALSE in Django before publishing my app, static files stop working anyway, which confuses me even more. So, I don't even know if my failed attempts are because of this debug setting or incorrect settings in the web.config file. But I will give your solution a try though and will let you know if it worked. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: The web.config file works fine for me.Hope it helps you! Any concern,please feel free to let me kown.